# How do I use a integer in query for a database?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

This is my current code:

```
var query = from o in this.appData.Personen
                            where o.Naam.Contains(txtSearch.Text) || o.Telefoonnummer.Contains(txtSearch.Text) || o._E_Mail_Adres == txtSearch.Text || o.Leeftijd == txtSearch.Text
                            select o;
```

These are my current errors:

> 'int' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best
>   extension method overload
>   'Queryable.Contains(IQueryable, string)' requires a
>   receiver of type 'IQueryable'

and:

> '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'string'

How do I use a integer with the current functions I'm trying to reach?

Please Note. My database is made in Access 2016. Naam and Leeftijd are two columns in my table set on Numeric. If there is a way to change these back to short text without messing up my code, I'd love to know.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: try `o.Telefoonnummer.ToString().Contains` and `o.Leeftijd.ToString() ==`

Answer (score 0):

Using `.Field<T>()`:

```
row.Field<UInt32>($COLUMN) == $UInt32
```